# Applying EWMA to first difference of a time series

Tags: time-series, forecasting, exponential-smoothing

I am trying to fit an EWMA to the first difference but I am unsure how to properly fit the EWMA and how to assess if one model is better than another. I am trying to use the EWMA described in the `forecast` package: https://training-course-material.com/training/R_-_Forecasting

The first difference occurs always at integer values, most of which are zero, i.e. $$x_i=1,0,0,0,0,3,-2,1,0,0,0,...$$

Are there any standard ways to modelling first differences with EWMA? When I try to auto-fit it, I get an extremely tiny $\alpha$. Also, if I wanted to determine if another timer-series variable is correlated with this EWMA, how should I compute this?

Answer (score 1):

You would typically not apply Single Exponential Smoothing (also known as Exponentially Weighted Average) to differenced series. Instead, you'd directly apply Double Exponential Smoothing, i.e., smoothing with a level and a trend component. [Here is the relevant section of *Forecasting: Principles and Practice*](http://otexts.org/fpp2/trend-methods.html).

If you really want to smoothe first differences, just do so by feeding them into `ets()` or similar. If the first differences come out close to zero, then this looks like there may not be all that much trend or other nonstationarity in the mean to your original series. In such a case, the smoothing constant for the differenced series will quite reasonably be close to zero.

If your differenced series are always integer, your original series are probably also integer. You may want to look into count data models, or possible intermittent demand forecasting.

Finally, *don't* assess whether a different series is correlated with a *smoothed* series. Correlations with smoothed series are biased: [Smoothing - when to use it and when not to?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/144013/1352)

Comment: Thanks a lot for that great answer. You addressed all my misunderstandings very well. I will read your sources.

Comment: Would it make sense to correlate a smoothed series with another smoothed series?

Comment: Also, smoothing the differences doesn't make much sense to me since the values are just integers on either side of zero for the course of the time series.